# How to configure initial evil-state for major mode

Tags: evil, bookmark+

When calling

> M-x bm-show-all

Emacs is in normal state. I've to push the "i" key to switch to insert then hitting Enter on a bookmark goto that bookmark.  I tried this :

```
(use-package evil
 :ensure t
 :config
 (setq evil-set-initial-state 'bm-bookmarks-mode 'insert))
```

but not working.  It is annoying to hit "i" to be able to go to a defined bookmark..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure `evil-insert-state` as the initial state for some major-mode you can add it to the list of `evil-insert-state-modes` either using Emacs customization (`M-x customize-variable` `evil-insert-state-modes`) or using the following elisp:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'evil-insert-state-modes 'bm-show-mode)
```

There exist similar variables for all other evil states.

B.t.w. evil already provides marks by itself, although they are not 'visible'. But you can make them visible using [evil-visual-mark-mode](https://melpa.org/#/evil-visual-mark-mode). You can read about how to use evil marks at https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_marks.